# Rally Javascript API: How can I determine the release of a requirement on a defect?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a Rally Javascript API app to break down defects reported within a release cycle into "current" and "prior".  Current = defects against stories in the selected release.  Prior = defects against stories in a prior release or with no associated story.  In both cases, the defect creation date must be within the date range of the release.

Here's the basic flow I was going for:

1. Select a release
2. Query all defects where CreationDate is within the selected release date range
3. If the defect has a Requirement and the Requirement is in the selected release, count as "current", otherwise count as "prior"

It seemed simple enough, but I've run into a roadblock in determining if the defect is reported against a story in the selected release or not.  Defects have a Requirement property which represents the story the defect is against, but the Requirement object does not have a Release property.  Only HierarchicalRequirement has a Release property.

Any thoughts on how to determine the release of a requirement on a defect?  Or maybe a different approach that could accomplish the same thing?

---

Per request for a code snippet:

I started with the [Defects by Closer](https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/697590494d/custom/6990991664) app from the catalog since it had the basic layout I wanted and just modified the query and table population logic.

Here's the query:

```
var relDateBeg = rally.sdk.util.DateTime.toIsoString(new Date(releaseDropdown.getSelectedStart()));
var relDateEnd = rally.sdk.util.DateTime.toIsoString(new Date(releaseDropdown.getSelectedEnd()));

var queryCriteria = '((CreationDate >= ' + relDateBeg + ') AND (CreationDate <= ' + relDateEnd + '))';
                var queryConfig =
                {
                    key   : "defects",
                    type  : "Defect",
                    fetch : "ObjectID,FormattedID,Name,ClosedDate,Requirement,CreationDate",
                    order : "FormattedID",
                    query : queryCriteria
                };
```

Then in the `showResults()` method that processes the query results, I iterate through all the defects and populate the table.  In this code I check if the defect has a Requirement, and if so, I wanted to check what release the Requirement belongs to so I could categorize the defect as "current" or "prior", but the Requirement object doesn't have a Release property.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that shows what you are trying to do?  What fetch paramaters are you specifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Release to your fetch.  That should include the release in the results for each defect and linked story.

Comment: OK, well I feel stupid.  Guess I should have tried that, but according to the API reference, Requirement doesn't have a Release property, nor does anything Requirement inherits from.  But something like defect.Requirement.Release.Name does in fact work if you include Release in the fetch (assuming the defect has a story and the story has a release, of course).  Thanks for the help.  This is going to be a huge time saver in pulling the metrics we're looking for.

Comment: Our api has lots of interesting nooks and crannies- it took me quite awhile to get my head around it.  Fetch is a bit strange since it will include that field on any sub object as well, even if the requested type doesn't have it.  Happy coding.